# How to animate uibuttons in a circular path (Objective C)

Tags: iphone, uibutton, core-animation

```
float degrees = -30.0;
float radians = (degrees/180.0) * M_PI;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^
 {
     bottomRoundedView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
 }
 ];
```

Comment: My need is to animate three buttons in a quarter circle. the selected item should be framed at center and the remaining buttons should align in order with consistency with circular animating effect

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with more text? Otherwise it deserve to close topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code,

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
pathAnimation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
pathAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear];
pathAnimation.duration = 3.0;

CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGRect circleContainer = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); 
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(curvedPath, NULL, circleContainer);

pathAnimation.path = curvedPath;
CGPathRelease(curvedPath);

[self.yourbutton.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"myCircleAnimation"];
```

`circleContainer` is the frame for which you need to show the circular animation.
`pathAnimation.duration` is to adjust the speed of the animation.

if you want to stop the animation then call

```
[self.yourbutton.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"myCircleAnimation"];
```